# cannot connect to postgres :psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL: password authentication failed for user on windows

Tags: authentication, psql, postgresql-12

I installed PostgreSQL on my windows 10 and while running the server in sql shell `(psql) (psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "samantha")`

This error is showing up

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

> psql -U postgres